# web scraping TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    # print(article.prettify())

    headline = article.h2.a.text
    print(headline)

    summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.text
    print(summary)

    vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_='youtube-player')['src'] ## getting error on this line
    vid_id = vid_src.split('/')[4]
    vid_id = vid_id.split('?')[0]
    # print(vid_id)

    yt_link = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={vid_id}'
    print(yt_link)
```

any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is, when you are looping through the articles, you are assuming all have the selectors you are looking for - in this case it's the youtube link.

One of the Articles doesn't have the selector you're looking for so will return None. If you look at the below it'll show that one of the Articles has no youtube link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    # print(article.prettify())
    try:
        headline = article.h2.a.text
        # print(headline)

        summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.text
        # print(summary)

        vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_='youtube-player')['src'] ## 
        getting error on this line
        vid_id = vid_src.split('/')[4]
        vid_id = vid_id.split('?')[0]
        # print(vid_id)

        yt_link = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={vid_id}'
        print(yt_link)
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)
```

Comment: The point was to add `try:`.